# Can't get the text between the opening and closing tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>'hello'<a>'my link'</a></p>", 'html.parser')
print(soup.p.string)
None
```

Is the output normal?

Comment: it was just a mistype here in stackoverflow. corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Althought `<\p>` is invalid, lxml will try to close the first tag, so this code works. html.parser does not make a good job on that field.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>'hello'<a>'my link'</a></p>", 'lxml')
print(soup.p.get_text(strip=True))
```

Which outputs:

> 'hello''my link'

Answer (score 1):

Since the initially posted `<\p>` was just a typo, here is what your problem is actually about.

It is about how `.string` works in `BeautifulSoup`. It works differently depending on the element's children - [if an element has multiple children, it returns `None`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`

Notice, how the `.string` for the `p` element is `None`, but for `a` it is not:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>'hello'<a>'my link'</a></p>", 'html.parser')

In [3]: print(soup.p.string)
None

In [4]: print(soup.p.a.string)
'my link'
```

The correct and more reliable way to get the element's text is via [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
In [5]: print(soup.p.get_text(strip=True))
'hello''my link'
```

Comment: Thanks for the huge clarification. Can you tell me what's the role of putting strip = true?

Comment: @HamzaKourati it just helps to get rid of the extra spaces and newlines around the text values. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>adA<a>asda</a>asda</p>")
>>> soup.p
<p>adA<a>asda</a>asda</p>
>>> soup.p.text
u'adAasdaasda'
```

I think that Bs can't really get only the paragraphs text because there is a a tag nested inside. I think that when you try to get the text it recursively gets the text from all children and appends it to the output.

Comment: Include a detailed explanation how do this solves the question's problem, don't just write the code.